# Angular 2.0 - Injected Http service is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

**Comment** - I managed to fix this issue, see in the bottom of this post

I am upgrading my Angular 1.X application using UpgradeAdapter (ngUpgrade). I added a new Angular 2.0 service which I call from my Angular 2.0 Component:

Service:

```
import {Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export default class MyService {
  _http;
  constructor(http: Http) {
    this._http = http; //http is undefined here
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(someUrl);
  }
}
```

Inside my `bootstrap.ts` I have:

```
declare var angular: any;

import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

let adapter = new UpgradeAdapter();

adapter.addProvider(Http);

//.....

adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**:

I am injecting another service (Angular 1.X upgraded service) to my Angular 2.0 service, and it does work:

```
import {Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export default class MyService {
  _http;
  _dataService;
  constructor( @Inject('dataService') dataService, http: Http) {
    this._http = http; //http is undefined here
    this._dataService = dataService; //dataService is defined!!
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(someUrl);
  }
}
```

Bootstrap.ts:

```
declare var angular: any;

import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

let adapter = new UpgradeAdapter();

adapter.addProvider(Http);

adapter.upgradeNg1Provider('dataService');

adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
```

**EDIT 2**:

When looking at my ES5 transpired code I found this code:

```
 MyService = __decorate([
        core_1.Injectable(),
        __param(0, core_1.Inject('dataService'))
    ], MyService);
    return MyService;
```

As you can see - no `http` injection to `MyService`. When changing my service constructor to use this syntax

```
constructor( @Inject('dataService') dataService, @Inject('Http') http)
```

Now I am getting the following error:

```
Error: No provider for Http!
```

**Solution for the problem:**

So I finally succeed, using a clue from @PierreDuc response:

I changed the constructor for MyService to be:

```
constructor( @Inject('dataService') dataService, @Inject(Http) http)
```

And I added `HTTP_PROVIDERS` as a provider to my component (which uses the service):
(inside my ng 2 component:)

`providers: [MyService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]`

No need for `@Injectable` or `addProvider` inside my bootstrap.

I do not fully understand why is this happening and why this solution worked. Will love to have it explained if someone here knows it.

**Solution Edit:**

After a little reading, I now understand DI better. I can use the `addProvider(HTTP_PROVIDERS)` instead of defining a provider for each component (it will be available for all components). The only mystery left is why injecting `private http: Http` doesn't work while `@Inject(Http) http` does work. Any idea???

Comment: _So I finally succeed, using a clue from @PierreDuc response_, you should probably give them some credit in that case :)

Comment: I did! But it is not a solution for the issue so I cannot mark it as an Answer because it wasn't the answer...

Comment: I'm late to the party, but for other future readers... "It is a "best practice" to apply the @Injectable() decorator ​[to all of your services] from the start​ both for consistency and for future-proofing" -- [Services tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in the bootstrap, and not just `Http`. Try this for `bootstrap.ts`

```
declare var angular: any;

import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

let adapter = new UpgradeAdapter();

adapter.addProvider(HTTP_PROVIDERS);

//.....

adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
```

**edit**

And above that `MyService.ts` must have an `@Injectable()` decorator to let angular know it has to inject its dependencies. The reason the injection of the `dataService` worked is because you used the decorator `@Inject`. Try this for `MyService.ts`

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export default class MyService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(someUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, you forgot one more thing. I'll edit my answer

Comment: without any network/console errors... that is odd. Are you sure you tried it with `Injectable` and not `Inject`?

Comment: Yes. I am adding some more details - see my edit. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot see a reason why it should not work. Adding `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to the adapter, and adding `@Injectable` really should have done the trick. Did you add the `angular2/bundles/http.min.js` script to the `index.html`?

Comment: I found a solution. Your HTTP_PROVIDERS was a clue, so thank you very much. - I am updating with the solution.

Comment: Adding `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to a component instead of the bootstrap sounds counter-intuitive to me. As well as using `@Inject` for every service/provider. There is a big chance adding the `@Injectable` to the `MyService` will work as well now (after adding http_providers to the component), without the need of adding `@Inject` inside the constructor. But, glad you found a solution :)

Comment: I know, this is odd. I will continue playing with this, thank you very much for the help!